# Why doesn't BETWEEN work in this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Query 1 works but query 2 doesn't:

Query #1:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE users.dob <= '1994-1-14' AND users.dob >= '1993-1-14' LIMIT 10
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE users.dob BETWEEN '1994-1-14' AND '1993-1-14' LIMIT 10
```

The 2nd one should be able to do the same thing as the first but I don't understand why it's not working.

The dob (date of birth) field in the users table is a type `date` field with records that look like this:

```
1988-11-08  
1967-11-14  
1991-03-09      
1958-03-08  
1967-06-30  
1988-10-19   
1986-01-23  
1965-09-20
```

**YEAR - MONTH - DAY**

With either query #1 or #2 I'm trying to get back all users who are between 18 and 19 years of age, because `1994-1-14` is exactly 18 years from today and `1993-1-14` is 19 years from today. So is there a way to get the between query to work?

By not working I mean it doesn't return any records from the db while the working query does.

Also is the `between` query more efficient or is the performance difference negligible?

Comment: Guessing you should switch the two dates around to get your between working:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is wrong. See the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) documentation:

`expr BETWEEN min AND max` is equivalent to `(min <= expr AND expr <= max)`.

Therefore, `users.dob BETWEEN '1994-1-14' AND '1993-1-14'` is the same as `('1994-1-14' <= users.dob  AND users.dob  <= '1993-1-14')`, of which there will never be more than 0 results.

Simply reverse the order :)

There will be no performance difference when using either form, possibly subject to the note below. This transformation happens at the query planner level. However, if you have concerns, remember to *profile, profile, profile*. Then you can see for yourself and appease the premature-optimization demons.

---

Also note the ... note:

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first part: "expr BETWEEN min AND max". Try switching those 2 dates in the second query.